# How to translate integer error-codes into human-readable strings?

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

IBM goes to great lengths documenting the possible error-codes for different MQ-related functions, but I cannot find an existing library function to translate the integer codes into human-readable strings.

Something like libc's `strerror(3)` or OpenSSL's `ERR_error_string(3)`...

I suppose, the programmers and operators are expected to have a handy (if dog-eared) reference book...

Or does the function exist -- and just is not easy to find?

Comment: You can create your own function easily with `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: If `ibm-mq` is opensource, you could find that in its source code, and perhaps even generate (e.g. with [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)) the C++ code of such a simple function. If `ibm-mq` is coded in Java, you could probably use Java class reflection to generate such a code

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - IBM MQ is not opensource, so you won't find it's source code, but the headers are available, and so is a function to convert number to constant string name.

Comment: If the C++ header are available, you are probably allowed to look inside them. Ask your lawyer for permission.

Comment: If the C++ header file is available, it could be processed by some `gawk` script

Comment: The headers are expected to be used by programmers, I don't think you need a lawyer to use the header files supplied :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the number, e.g. 2035, into a string such as "MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED" using the `MQRC_STR` function that is shipped in header file `cmqstrc.h`.

If you want more than just the string representation of the constant, you could look into calling the `mqrc` executable that is shipped with distributed platform versions of IBM MQ, and scraping the output. In my view the string version of the constant is enough for most people.

```
#include <cmqc.h>                   /* Include for MQI Constants */
#include <cmqstrc.h>                /* Convert MQRC into string  */

:

MQCONN(QMName,
       &hConn,
       &CompCode,
       &Reason);
if (Reason)
{
  printf("MQCONN to QMgr %.48s failed with reason %d (%s)\n",
         QMName, Reason, MQRC_STR(Reason));
  :
}
```

Comment: I don't have `cmqstrc.h` in the SDK version 7.5.0 -- is the header a later addition to the kit? Grepping through all other headers for the function name does not yield anything either :(

Comment: `cmqstrc.h` is in MQ V8 or higher.  You can grab it from a higher release and use it.  It just has subroutines for each MQ field type with switch/case statements.  For one-off outputting switch/case is fine but if you were doing something extremely repetitive then you should write your own binary search algorithm.

Comment: I posted a [blog item](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6360) that provides a header file with code for looking up MQ Completion and Reason Codes.

Comment: As @Roger has answered, you can use a later version of the header without any issue. I would also recommend installing a somewhat newer version of MQ anyway, as V7.5 has been out of service for a while now.

Comment: Thanks, Roger and Morag. Can't help not to snipe, that up to the *eighth* major release, a large software package didn't have a library call to decipher error-codes. This is so IBMish, it hurts...

Comment: @MikhailT. that comment makes no sense.  The reason codes in `cmqstrc.h` for subroutine MQRC_STR() are **_already sorted_**.  The MQRC_STR() uses switch/case logic, hence, it **_IS_** performing a linear/sequential search.  Therefore, everything explained in my blog posting is correct.

Comment: Which is why I deleted my comment :) Let's both do it again -- for posterity...

Comment: @MikhailT. - I think back in the bad old days (!!) we all had our own routines and so no-one asked IBM to make one. I still only use `MQRC_STR` if I am writing sample code to give to someone. The rest of the time I use our own routines for this purpose.

Comment: @MoragHughson, "no one asked"? The `strerror()` function I mention, which returns textual explanation for `errno`-codes, is with us since 4.4BSD -- that's circa *1993*. Some things should not require asking, frankly.

Comment: @MikhailT. IBM is like most software companies (including mine), you design and create a product with many features.  But software companies cannot read the mind of the end-users.  IBM has a process for end-users to submit requests for new features/enhancements called RFE (Request For Enhancement).

Comment: @MikhailT. For me, when a new customer is trying out a product, I always say "if you think product 'x' is missing a feature please let me know'.  If I had to guess, I think at least 60% of the features in our products come from end-user requests.  Moral of the story is that software companies are not mind readers. Hence, ask if you want some thing.

Comment: To put it in your terms, @Roger, a function translating error-codes belongs in the other 40%... And it ought to be fast too -- as in your implementation -- not slow as in IBM's.